# Grammatically correct indefinite article in Python

Tags: python-3.x, random

I am creating a random sentence generator that can apply the
correct indefinite article (a, an) to the sentence.
But I am getting results such as these:
I eat a apple. I ride an bike. You eat an apple.
"a" should come before the consonant, and "an" should come before the vowel: an apple; a bike.
**What am I doing wrong?**

```
Import random
def main():
    pronoun = ["I ", "You "]
    verb = ["kick ", "ride", "eat "]
    noun = [" ball.", " bike.", " apple.", " elephant."]
    ind_art = "an" if random.choice(noun[0]).lower() in "aeiou" else "a"

    a = random.choice(pronoun)
    b = random.choice(verb)
    c = ind_art
    d = random.choice(noun)

    print(a+b+c+d)
main()
```

Comment: This doesn't really affect my answer, but `random.choice(noun[0])` in your code doesn't look right to me; I would have expected `random.choice(noun)[0]`.

Comment: Pedant's Corner: in English, the choice of "a" or "an" depends on the initial vowel *sound* rather than the initial letter (e.g. "a one-way street" *vs* "an onion"); and also whether a noun is singular or plural (e.g. "an apple" *vs* "some apples" - but not "a apples").

Answer (score 2):

When you call `random.choice` it returns a new value each time. So the random word in the line where you create your `ind_art` is a different word from the one that gets assigned to `d`.

You need to reorder your code so that `d` is used when determining the article.

```
d = random.choice(noun)
ind_art = "an" if d[0].lower() in "aeiou" else "a"
```

Comment: Should be `d[1]`, since `d[0]` is always a space.

Comment: Changing d[0] to d[1] along with the above suggestion worked. So, thanks Sam and Keith.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed some lines in your code. Now, it works fine.

```
import random
def main():
    pronoun = ["I ", "You "]
    verb = ["kick ", "ride ", "eat "]
    noun = ["ball.", "bike.", "apple.", "elephant."]
    ch = random.choice(noun).lower()   # <===== fixed this line
    # print(ch[0]) # test
    ind_art = "an " if ch[0] in "aeiou" else "a "  # <===== fixed this line

    a = random.choice(pronoun)
    b = random.choice(verb)
    c = ind_art
    # d = random.choice(noun)   # <===== removed this line

    print(a+b+c+ch)  # <===== replaced d with ch
main()
```

Comment: This does work. I am confused as to why this and the other suggestion works, when they are both using a different index number. But anyway, thanks.

Comment: This version works with the index 0 because it removes the space from the front of the noun and instead puts it after the article. In practice, it'd probably be easier to remove all the spaces from the word lists and add them at the end: `print(' '.join([a, b, c, ch]))`